# cognos report sorting different when exporting to excel

Tags: export-to-excel, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

im new to cognos reporting. I have created a report using report studio. It has tables and charts.

Then I added an export link to excel using drill down.

The problem occurs when im doing export. The sort order in html version is different in the exported version.

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks.

Already solved the problem. I just need to set the category axis property of reverse category order to NO then problem solved.

Comment: Do you have a sort defined in your report? Unless you have a sort explicitly defined you can't rely on any sort order in the output.

If you do have a sort defined and either HTML or Excel is disobeying that sort, then you have a bug.

Comment: Yes i have defined the sorting field in my report. It is sorting properly when i run it using hrml version. But when i export it. It is different order.

Comment: This might be a bug. There are quite a few sorting fixes listed here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027081. but you need to specify if it's a list/crosstab, what the sorting is based on, is this upgraded etc. I know that a generated HTML query can be very different to a Excel one, as HTML does not fetch all the rows first.

Comment: Why don't you put your solution in the answer (with a bit more detail) and accept your own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution. Since we've migrated from cognos 8 to cognos 10. The charts was not migrated properly. So I just did a convert chart so it will be migrated to cognos 10. After doing that, I just need to set the category axis property of reverse category order to NO then problem solved.

Thanks.